# Using forEach with Callbacks function with asyncawait

Tags: node.js, async-await

im try to use [asyncawait](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) on a cronjob with callback, this callback are data from an API:

This is part of the code:

```
var sending_email = new CronJob({
    cronTime: time_hour,
    onTick: function(){
        console.log('Funciona cada: ', time_hour);

        sendService.GetSenderList(function(datos){
            console.log('a enviar: ', datos);
            var arrayInfo = [];

            await (
                datos.forEach(function(hash){
                //console.log('a enviar: ', hash.HASH_TOKEN);

                    var wait = sendService.GetMailContent(hash.HASH_TOKEN, function(content){
                        arrayInfo.push(content);
                        console.log(hash.HASH_TOKEN,content);
                    });
                })
            );

            console.log('array: ',arrayInfo);
        })
    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'Chile/Continental'
})
```

And my function to get api are:

```
exports.GetSenderList = async (function(callback){
    await (client.get(constant.API_URL_SENDER, function (data, response) {
        callback(data);
    }));    
});

exports.GetMailContent = async.iterable (function(hash,callback){
    await (client.get(constant.API_URL_CONF+'/'+hash, function(data, response) {
        callback(data)
    }))
})
```

Could you helpme, i can't fixed, i try with return instead of callback, but still doen't work...

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

i change my code, thanks [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)...

using "node-rest-client-promise"

```
var constant = require('./constant.json')
var mailConfig = require('./mailConfig.json')
// var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;
//var async = require('asyncawait/async');
//var await = require('asyncawait/await');

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

//var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
//var client = new Client();

var nodeRestClient = require('node-rest-client-promise');
var client = nodeRestClient.Client({
    requestConfig: {
        timeout: 30000, //request timeout in milliseconds 
        noDelay: true, //Enable/disable the Nagle algorithm 
        keepAlive: true, //Enable/disable keep-alive functionalityidle socket. 
        keepAliveDelay: 100000 //and optionally set the initial delay before the first keepalive probe is sent 
    },
    responseConfig: {
        timeout: 50000 //response timeout 
    }
});


exports.GetSenderList = function() {
    let lista = client.getPromise(constant.API_URL_SENDER);
    //console.log('Get lista: ',lista)
    return lista
};

exports.GetMailContent = function(hash) {
    var normalHash = hash.replace(new RegExp("/", 'g'),"%2F");
    //console.log(normalHash);
    let lista = client.getPromise(constant.API_URL_CONF + '/' + normalHash);
    return lista
};
```

and on cron:

```
var sending_email = new CronJob({
    cronTime: time_hour,
    onTick: async function(){
        console.log('Funciona cada: ', time_hour);

        let arrayInfo = [];
        let arrayHash = [];
        let datos;

        try{
            datos = await sendService.GetSenderList();

            //console.log('datos: ', datos.data);

            for(let hash of datos.data){
              //console.log('hash', hash);
              let content = await sendService.GetMailContent(hash.HASH_TOKEN)
              arrayHash.push(hash.HASH_TOKEN);
              arrayInfo.push(content.data);
            }

            console.log('array: ', arrayInfo);
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log("onTick error ", e);
        }
    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'Chile/Continental'
})
```

Comment: what is the error or what is the output your getting?

Comment: Is not a error, just return with different times, so i cant match the hash i send with the answer!

Comment: We have to see the code inside of `client.get()`.  It appears to be an odd function because it is asynchronous, but has no way of communicating back an error.  There is likely a design problem with that function unless there is no possible error from it.

Comment: I temporarily deleted my answer because I realized that `util.promisify()` will not work with `client.get()` because it does not follow the classic node.js callback interface for asynchronous operations (the callback should be `(error, result)`, but yours is `(data, response)` which won't work with `util.promisify()`.  That's why it was always giving you an error.  I can fix my answer if you show us the code for `client.get()` so we can properly promisify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await arr.forEach()` doesn't work as you'd expect. In your case, you want to use `map()` to make it so you're awaiting on an array of promises.

`await (Promise.all(datos.map(hash => sendService.GetMailContent(hash.HASH_TOKEN))));`

I wrote a detailed blog post about making `forEach()` work with async/await, check it out if you want to learn more: http://thecodebarbarian.com/basic-functional-programming-with-async-await#motivation-and-foreach-